# specflow behind code has syntax error or duplicate code

Tags: c#, msbuild, specflow

I have a solution that consists of a couple of projects. I have 3 categories of projects in my solution. First category only includes the .feature files. The second category only includes the bindings. The third includes the drivers which include a set of functions used in the bindings to communicate with a software interface which I am testing.

When I build my solution, some of the code behind files (.feature.cs) become corrupted. Here are screenshots of what I get after I build the solution:

Build errors in Visual Studio

[Build errors in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcUtv.jpg)

Below is an example of a corrupted .feature.cs file:

```
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <auto-generated>
//      This code was generated by SpecFlow (http://www.specflow.org/).
//      SpecFlow Version:2.3.0.0
//      SpecFlow Generator Version:2.3.0.0
// 
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </auto-generated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#region Designer generated code
#pragma warning disable
namespace AcceptanceTests.Controllers.Images
{
    using TechTalk.SpecFlow;


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "2.3.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute()]
    public partial class GetImagesFeature
    {

        private static TechTalk.SpecFlow.ITestRunner testRunner;

        pr// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <auto-generated>
//      This code was generated by SpecFlow (http://www.specflow.org/).
//      SpecFlow Version:2.3.0.0
//      SpecFlow Generator Version:2.3.0.0
// 
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </auto-generated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Designer generated code
```

Notice how there are duplicate blocks of code here. It seems like the regenerated code was added somewhere in the middle of the older code (where we see "pr// --- ").

Another example would be a behind code file with syntax error like missing brackets or improper formatting.

All the test projects in my solution have the following packages:

- MSTest.TestAdapter v1.3.2
- MSTest.TestFramework v1.3.2
- SpecFlow v2.3.1
- SpecFlow.MsTest v2.3.1
- .Net Framework 4.6.2

The unit test provider is mstest.v2.

So far I have tried to clean the SpecFlow files in %TEMP%. I made sure that all projects have the same version of SpecFlow installed. I have cleaned the solution and done rebuilds. If I run the custom tool on each feature file individually I never get this problem.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you building in parallel, perhaps?

Comment: @Zer0 Not sure. How would I check that?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 uses Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> maximum number of parallel project builds.  `msbuild` uses the command line switch `-maxcpucount`, or `-m` for short.

Comment: @Zer0 Thanks for the info! That number is 8.
Why would this number be an issue?

Comment: This has nothing to do with parallel build.
Please open an issue on https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow

Comment: Did you clean your build beforehand? That means deleting all the computer generated files before you build.

Comment: @CJohnson If I do that, I would have to regenerate them one by one. The feature.cs files don't get regenerated during the build if they are deleted. Plus, I have like 20 to 40 feature files.

Comment: So what if you have to regenerate them?! Delete them. That is the definition of a good build. It can build correctly from a clean slate. When you leave garbage in your code files you are re-enforcing bad and random behavior.

Comment: @CJohnson So I need to remove them first, then build the solution, then regenerate/create them one by one? 
I have done that with a couple of them but they get corrupted again

Comment: So you are going to have to then upload some code samples that demonstrate the behavior for us to look at. When we can't see your code, there is not much we can do.

Comment: It looks like the issue is caused by projects with long names, nested folders and long test scenario descriptions. I shorten the scenario description in one of the feature files that constantly had its behind code corrupted and the problem went away after that. I will leave that as a solution to this issue once I do enough testing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by projects with long names, nested folders and long test scenario descriptions. I shorten the scenario descriptions in one of the feature files that constantly had its behind code corrupted and the problem went away after that.